# How do I relate the variance, V(Y), to units of time given in this problem?

Tags: probability

Twenty percent of the items being made are defective.  Defective items take 8 minutes to prepare for use while non-defective items take 2 minutes to prepare for use. 10  items are randomly selected right after being made. Their defective or non-defective status are independent of each other. Let Y = # of defective items out of the  10  selected.  Find the variance of the time these 10 items take to be prepared for use.

To find the mean, I used the fact that E(Y) = np = 2, meaning two defectives are produced on average, and thus that 8 of the 10 selected will be non-defective on average. The average time it takes to prepare these items will then be 2(8 minutes) + 8(2 minutes) = 32 minutes.

However, I'm not sure how to find the variance of the time. I know that V(Y) = npq = (10)(.2)(.8) = 1.6, but I do not understand what this number represents in this context, and so I don't know how to apply the preparation times to it in order to find the variance of the times. Can someone please explain how to move forward from here?

Comment: Perhaps it clarifies things to subtract $2$ minutes from all the times.  Thus imagine it takes $6$ mins for a defective one and $0$ for a non-defective one.  Subtracting a constant doesn't change the variance.  Now the time $T$ as a random variable is just $6Y$.

Comment: @lulu So with this the varience would be 6^2(1.6), or 36(1.6) = 57.6. But what does this number represent in this context, and why would it be no different if we had not simplified the time parameters?

Comment: The true distribution of time is $S=6Y+20$.  The additive constant does not alter the variance.

Comment: @lulu I'm not seeing where this comes from, mainly the +20. Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: $Y$ is the number of defective ones.  $10-Y$ is the number of non-defective ones.  Total time is $S=8Y+2(10-Y)=6Y+20$.